# Composite unique using constraints SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have supplier table with supplier id as the primary key. I have a supplier type column which can be airline (AL), hotel (HT), Tour (T).

For the supplier type airline (AL) I want the `airline_type` and `airline_abbr` columns to be composite unique as well as the `airline_type` and `airline_iata_code` to be composite unique.

I don't want to set this as the primary key because primary key is already declared.

How to go about it? Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create unique filtered indices on your table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Airline_TypeAbbr
ON dbo.Supplier (airline_type, airline_abbr)
WHERE supplier_type = 'AL'

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Airline_TypeIataCode
ON dbo.Supplier (airline_type, airline_iata_code)
WHERE supplier_type = 'AL'
```

You can read more about what filtered indexes are and how to use them in Pinal Dave's [excellent blog post on the topic](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/01/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-filtered-index-improve-performance-with-filtered-index/)